# Intuit Quickbooks API with iOS - Email RFC822 Error

Tags: ios, quickbooks

I have an iOS app that uses Quickbooks API to add customer's to the Customer table in QB.  I am receiving the following error every time I try to add a customer:

```
  "Email Address does not conform to the syntax rules of RFC 822. Supplied value:Optional(\"\\mrad@test.com\\\")","code":"2210","element":"PrimaryEmailAddr"}],"type":"ValidationFault"},"time":"2020-04-03T04:44:23.174-07:00"},"intuit_tid":"1-5e872b0a-7f5bb1ee5417f09c63ea8d0e"}
```

The code I'm using to add the customer is:

```
                let qbParams = [
                    "billingFullName" : billingNameTextField.text!,
                    "email" : "mrad@test",
                    "billingLastName" : "Mike",
                    "billingFirstName" : "Smith",
                    "phoneNumber" : phoneNumber!,
                    "billingCity" : billingCityTextField.text!,
                    "billingState" : billingStateTextField.text!,
                    "billingZip" : billingZipTextField.text!,
                    "billingAddressOne" : billingAddressOneTextField.text!,
                    "billingAddressTwo" : billingAddressTwoTextField.text!,
                    "ccNum" : ccNumberTextField.text!,
                    "ccExpMonth" : ccExpMonth,
                    "ccExpYear" : ccExpYear,
                    "ccCVC" : ccCVVTextField.text!,
                    "addressOne" :  addressOne,
                    "addressTwo" : addressTwo,
                    "city": city!,
                    "state": state!,
                    "zip": zip!
                ]

            let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
            manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 5
            manager.request("\(baseURL)/api/qb-signup", method: .post, parameters:
                qbParams as Parameters).responseString {
                    response in
                    if response.result.isSuccess {
                        let registerJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
                        print(registerJSON)
                    }
                    else {
                        print("API Call not Successful")
                        print(response)
                    }
                }
```

As you can see, I've hardcoded the email address for the purposes of the test.  I have also tried this with putting apostrophes around the test and I get the same result:

```
  "Email Address does not conform to the syntax rules of RFC 822. Supplied value:Optional(\"\\'mrad@test.com\\'\")","code":"2210","element":"PrimaryEmailAddr"}],"type":"ValidationFault"},"time":"2020-04-03T05:24:42.174-07:00"},"intuit_tid":"1-5e872b0a-7f5bb1ee5417f09c63ea8d0e"}
```

The email address seems to be valid to me.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of red flags here for you to track down:

In you code you're using this email address (which is definitely *not* valid - there's no TLD `.com` on the end of it):

```
"email" : "mrad@test",
```

vs. the error message which indicates you're sending:

```
mrad@test.com
```

So either you didn't paste what you're actually sending, or something else is transforming the email address before you send it.

Also, this URL:

```
\(baseURL)/api/qb-signup
```

Is not a URL that QuickBooks uses in any of it's endpoints. So, you're *not even sending this data to QuickBooks* unless there's some other layer or application here relaying the data (in which case you should post *that* code).

I'm also extremely suspicious that you're sending what you think you're sending, because QuickBooks seems to think you're sending this string:

```
"Optional(\"\\'mrad@test.com\\'\")"
```

e.g. you're actually sending `Optional(...` in the email address field. That looks like a type-cast of a Java `Optional` object to a `String` maybe?

Comment: on the first one, yes this is just a copy/paste issue as I was editing my real email address :).

Comment: On the API URL, this is the url in my actual code. This error is being returned from QB so it's definitely reaching QB just not proceeding.  My code rests in Azure an that's where this is being called.  Lastly I suspect you may be right on the optional piece but I'm not convinced that's correct as all the other fields being sent have "Optional" in them and send without an issue.  Going to have to investigate that further.

Comment: While that might be the actual URL in your code, _it's not an actual QuickBooks URL_. Are you 100% SURE you're posting _directly to QuickBooks_?  I think you're posting data to some intermediary service (Autofy? some REST service you created which abstracts the connect to QuickBooks? using some QuickBooks library maybe?) and not to QuickBooks itself. That's going to make your debugging _really_ hard...